# hashmap attribute input in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, input, hashmap

my entity class is Result

```
package com.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


  @Entity
   public class Result implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

      public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
       }

      public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
       }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(HashMap<String, Integer> mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    private Student student;
    private HashMap<String,Integer> mark;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
     }

   }
```

and my controller function is from where i want to show a form with Result entitiy

```
  @RequestMapping(value="show_mark",method = RequestMethod.GET)

      public ModelAndView show_subject_mark(){

       ModelAndView mav =new ModelAndView("add_subject_mark");

       mav.addObject("Result",new Result());

       return mav;

     }
```

my JAVA server page file is

```
 <html>
      <head>
        </head>
         <body>
           <form:form method="post"  
                      action="add_subject_mark" 
                      commandName="Result">

           </form:form>
         </body>
    </html>
```

now how can I use hash-map attribute of result entity to get input in jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to incorporate JSTL into your project to accomplish this without using scriptlets (should be avoided).

Add the directive at the top of your page:

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

As well as the dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use the following JSTL tags on your page:

```
<c:forEach var="mark" items="${Result.mark}">
    <form:input path="Result.mark['${mark.key}']"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: how can i use it into a form input field.

Comment: See update but you will need to add the keys prior to passing the map.  If you know the keys, just hardcode them like:  `<form:input path="Result.mark['keyName']"/>` and disregard the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through two different methods
1) Scriplets
2) JSTL tags

1)Scriplets

```
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
     <body>
       <form:form method="post" action="add_subject_mark" commandName="Result">
            <%
                Result result = (Result) request.getAttribure("Result");
                HashMap<String,Integer> mark = result.getMark(); //There u got the HashMap

             %>
       </form:form>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i know how to get hashmap but i want to know how to use it into a form input field?